# require in PHP 5.5.14 throwing warning and errors

Tags: php

I am receiving the below warnings/errors. I have a script that has a require() at the beginning of it. I was using the same script with PHP 5.3.3 and it runs fine, but with PHP 5.4.30 and PHP 5.5.14 I am receiving the the below messages. I have checked what have been changed/deprecated/removed before moving the code. I think I have missed some information somewhere. Your help is highly appreciated. This setup is in a Windows 2008 server

Note: In the error message below for some reason the \epo becomes ←epo

Thanks,

> Warning: require(c:←po\php\util\alpha.php): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\epo\php\PO\createInfo.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'c:←epo\php\util\alpha.php' (include_path='.;C:\php-5.5.14\pear') in C:\epo\php\PO\createInfo.php on line 3

Comment: See those little arrows in your path names? They'll probably be from you cutting and pasting a filename from a rich text editor like MS Word. Correct your path names and you will fix your problem. P.s. to fix this, click next to the arrow, press backspace until it's gone, then replace it with a `:`

Comment: Ahhh windows hosting.

Comment: @scrowler I'd recommend replacing the absolute path with `__DIR__ . '/../util/alpha.php'`. Portable code is happy code :D

Comment: @scrowler Might also be the result of `\r` getting turned into a carriage return character? (First path component is probably supposed to be "repo", not "epo".)

Comment: @duskwuff possibly, although the path at the end of the error notice shows the host script path as `\epo`

Comment: @duskwuff the host path is correct. it is C:\epo...

Comment: @scrowler The code has not been touched when I install php 5.5 nor copied from MS word. Currently the same code works perfectly fine when I run it under php 5.3. Now, I am pretty positive that the code is not the issue, for some odd reason it is not running in 5.4 either. One solution is using double backslash C:\\epo\\php\\util\\alpha.php OR using forward slash C:/epo/php/util/alpha.php I literately spent 6 hours reading the documentation for upgrading from 5.3 to 5.4 and for 5.4 to 5.5 and I don't see any changes to require or include.

Comment: I have another path that is included that works fine with a singe backslash. I wonder it "\e" is something that is introduced. According to (www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) "\e" is _escape (hex 1B)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is that you avoid using "\e" in you paths or strings. Since PHP 5.4 more specifically (php-5.4.4) \e, which is code for ESC was implemented and that is what was causing my code to fail. Theoretically, in Widowns it is always better to use \ instead of just a single \ in paths since backslash is known to be used as an escape character. Another was to do it is to use "/" forward slash and you will buy yourself a piece of mind.

For those who are curious The bug was fixed in PHP 5.4.4 [[bug #61827]](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61827)

Cheers,